# JQuery on click or on blur, stop or kill function because of scrolling conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am running smooth scrolling by this code: and all works great! my problem is that i have booking script that one of the fields(input) is select time.
 when you click on the field in will show popup with all the horse of the day.
 you can see working example [here](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/time.htm) as you can see the timer also using scrolling to allow you choose some hours. the problem is that the timer scrolling not working smooth scrolling function. i tried to kill the scrolling function by this code:

```
$( "#rtb-time" ).die( "blur", scrolling );
```

but this not working. please advise how to fix this issue

```
var scrolling = function(){ 
    var $window = $(window);
    var scrollTime = 0.8;
    var scrollDistance = 170;

    $window.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(event){

        event.preventDefault(); 

        var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta/120 || -event.originalEvent.detail/3;
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
        var finalScroll = scrollTop - parseInt(delta*scrollDistance);

        TweenMax.to($window, scrollTime, {
            scrollTo : { y: finalScroll, autoKill:true },
                ease: Power1.easeOut,
                overwrite: 5                            
            });

    });
};
scrolling();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using event.stopPropagation() on a element wrapping the time picker.

e.g.

```
$(document).on("scoll", ".picker_holder", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

It will prevent the scroll event from reaching your "$window", and stop it from scrolling when you scroll the time picker.

Comment: Hi @Sandhje Bouw it did not help.